# Basic Authentication on IIS Express

Tags: iis-express

I've searched for a while now but I can't seem to find the answer. There are ways of disabling/enabling anonymous and windows authentication. Does anyone know how to enable basic authentication on IIS Express (8.0) in Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Update `ApplicationHost.config`

In the the `ApplicationHost.config` file, find the following nodes and update the values:

```xml
<sectionGroup name="authentication">
   <basicAuthentication enabled="false" /> <!-- set to false -->
</sectionGroup>

<!-- ... -->

<authentication>
   <section name="basicAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" /> <!-- set to allow -->
</authentication>
```

#### Locate `ApplicationHost.config`

- **VS 2015** *and above* (per Joost's answer):

  ```
  sln_folder/.vs/applicationhost.config
  ```
- **VS 2013** *and below*:

  ```
  %UserProfile%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
  ```

  As far as I know, there is no way to enable it for only one project.

Comment: What if I only want to enable it for one particular project? This sounds like it will be enabled for all sites running on the IIS express

Comment: slight correction: overrideModeDefault="true" should be overrideModeDefault="Allow" --- but this information will get you there, paired with 2015 .vs directory info from Joost Aarts said.  -- Confirmed with VS 2015

Comment: VS 2019 - 2022.01.12.

This only worked for me, If I changed my project's own config file under Project/.vs/Project/config/applicationhost.config, and set the
<basicAuthentication enabled="false"> to TRUE. Strange.

Answer (score 24):

An additional heads up, in Visual Studio 2015, the location of the applicationhost.config file that is actually being used is inside a folder called .vs inside your solution folder. The one in your user profile is not being used

Comment: Be aware that .vs is a hidden file.

Comment: After much facepalming, I finally got a straight answer here.  So *that's* where they hid the applicationhost.config.  Jeezus.

Answer (score 2):

Here are slightly more details than the previous answer had:

1. %USERPROFILE%\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config:
   <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
2. In the same file: set
   <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" userName="" />
3. If you are not using domain test accounts, create a local user account **with the password** for the test login.

Answer (score 1):

For VS 2022 users under Windows 11 home:

1. Look for 'applicationhost.config' file...
2. Located at '...source\repos\ -your app name- .vs\config\applicationhost.config'......
3. Set 'enable' to 'true' value as showed in the image below:

[image]

4. In my case no extra steps needed.

note: '.vs' is a hidden item. You have to unhidden it.